# How would I group the "0 comparison value" of a ruby array after sorting them?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash, grouping

I have a list of players with ratings, wins, losses, and win loss percentages. I use sort_by to sort them by ratings then win loss percentages, and finally by number of wins. However, I also need to group the ones that are the same ranking together. According to the ruby sort_by docs [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), the sorting block calculates a `-1,0,+1`. I need to group the results that are `0` according to the sorting algorithm.

I would like to then return them as a hash with rank as one key and the player as the other key. How would I start to accomplish that?

Thank you!

Here is code that I have so far but I just don't know how to group them together.

```
# User.rb
def self.all_rankings
  sorted_rankings = self.searchable.sort_by do |user|
    [-user.rating, -user.all_wins_losses_as_decimal, -user.all_wins]
  end
  rank = 1
  sorted_rankings.map.with_index(1) do |user, index|
    {
      "rank": index,
      "user": user
    }
  end
end
```

EDIT: Here is a sample of the desired API output. However, I would like to group the rank of the user together. So, for example, I sort based on the `rating`, `all_wins_losses_as_decimal`, and `all_wins` in that order. If two users have the same `rating`, `all_wins_losses_as_decimal`, and `all_wins`, then those two users should have the same rank.

```
"users": [
    {
      "id": 560,
      "name": "Aaron Rodgers",
      "rank": 1,
      "z_rating": 40,
      "all_wins": 2,
      "all_losses": 0,
      "all_wins_losses_percentage": "1.000"
    },
    {
      "id": 559,
      "name": "Director Sports",
      "rank": 2,
      "z_rating": 40,
      "all_wins": 1,
      "all_losses": 0,
      "all_wins_losses_percentage": "1.000"
    },
    {
      "id": 571,
      "name": "Alford Schamberger",
      "rank": 3,
      "z_rating": 40,
      "all_wins": 1,
      "all_losses": 1,
      "all_wins_losses_percentage": ".500"
    }
]
```

I was thinking of accomplishing that by creating a hash of the user's rank and the user object to return the `z_rating`, `all_wins`, `all_losses`, and `all_wins_losses_percentage`.

The `rating` is an attribute of the `User` model. The `all_wins_losses_as_decimal` is a method on the `User` class which returns a `Float` type. The `all_wins` is another method on the `User` class which returns an `Int`

Comment: What does your desired result look like? Please edit your question to include some sample inputs and output.

Comment: Hint: When you say "I need to group" you probably mean [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). This question is hard to answer with a minimal use case with sample data and expected results.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the confusion. I have added more information to clear things up. Let me know if you need more information. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert and not sure if this would work but could you now simply `Hash.select` and lets say

```
h1.select { |key, value| value == '0' }
h1.select { |key, value| value == '1' }
```

and so on and you could asing value 0 -1 1 to whatever you want?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I don't have the `value` that you presented here. If I can return the value -1, 0 or +1 from ruby sort, then I would be able to group them but I don't know how to get that from the ruby sorting.

Answer (score 0):

The `0` result is the result of comparison with `<=>` so you could always write a solution like

```
# User.rb
def self.all_rankings
  sorted_rankings = self.searchable.sort_by do |user|
    [-user.rating, -user.all_wins_losses_as_decimal, -user.all_wins]
  end
  rank = 1
  rankings = Hash.new []
  selected_rating = sorted_rankings[0]
  sorted_rankings.each do |user|
     if selected_rating <=> user != 0
       selected_rating = user
       rank += 1
     end
     rankings[rank] << ranking
  end
  return rankings
end
```

Effectively your output would be a hash with a hash with the rank as the key and the array of users as the value. Effectively grouping all users of equivalent rank.